# How can I remove punctuation from input text in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, formatting

I am trying to get a sentence using input from the user in Java, and i need to make it lowercase and remove all punctuation. Here is my code:

```
    String[] words = instring.split("\\s+");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        words[i] = words[i].toLowerCase();
    }
    String[] wordsout = new String[50];
    Arrays.fill(wordsout,"");
    int e = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i] != "") {
            wordsout[e] = words[e];
            wordsout[e] = wordsout[e].replaceAll(" ", "");
            e++;
        }
    }
    return wordsout;
```

I cant seem to find any way to remove all non-letter characters. I have tried using regexes and iterators with no luck. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

This first removes all non-letter characters, folds to lowercase, then splits the input, doing all the work in a single line:

```
String[] words = instring.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase().split("\\s+");
```

Spaces are initially left in the input so the split will still work.

By removing the rubbish characters *before* splitting, you avoid having to loop through the elements.

Comment: If the goal is to remove punctuation, wouldn't `replaceAll("\\p{P}", "")` make more sense?

Comment: @VGR based on the title yes, but OP clarifies in question *remove all non-letter characters*

Comment: Is "å" a letter? Since that character would be removed.

Comment: @hendy yes, "å" is a Unicode "letter". I answered for a Latin context. To cater for *any* letter, the regex would be `"[^\\p{L} ]"`, which uses the POSIX notation for "letter".

Comment: I wonder if Unicode awareness should be a "default practice" to most/beginning programmers? What I mean is, an American/Indonesian programmers never needed to deal with strange characters in their "real" life. So their code probably reflects this, so even though they use UTF8, there're _unintentional_ assumption that letters are A-Z. A Turkish or Arabic programmer OTOH will recognize this scenario in the first place and seek Unicode solution. What do you think? (This is just a side discussion)

Comment: @ilija139 of course - all non-letter/space are removed in the first step. To retain digits too, just add digits to the characters being kept - ie change to `replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "")`

Answer (score 40):

You can use following [regular expression construct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

> Punctuation: One of !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~

```
inputString.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");
```

Answer (score 10):

You may try this:-

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Type a sentence and press enter.");
String input = scan.nextLine();
String strippedInput = input.replaceAll("\\W", "");
System.out.println("Your string: " + strippedInput);
```

`[^\w]` matches a non-word character, so the above regular expression will match and remove all non-word characters.

Comment: This will not replace digits. Which I guess comes under non-letter.

Comment: @RohitJain:- Yes I got your point. But I thought the punctuation which we often used in language. I took the literal meaning of punctuation!!!

Comment: @RohitJain yes, I do want to remove numbers. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to use RegEx (which seems highly unnecessary given your problem), perhaps you should try something like this:

```
public String modified(final String input){
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(final char c : input.toCharArray())
        if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(c))
            builder.append(Character.isLowerCase(c) ? c : Character.toLowerCase(c));
    return builder.toString();
}
```

It loops through the underlying `char[]` in the `String` and only appends the `char` if it is a letter or digit (filtering out all symbols, which I am assuming is what you are trying to accomplish) and then appends the lower case version of the `char`.

Answer (score 5):

I don't like to use regex, so here is another simple solution.

```
public String removePunctuations(String s) {
    String res = "";
    for (Character c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(c))
            res += c;
    }
    return res;
}
```

**Note: This will include both Letters and Digits**

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to REMOVE punctuation, then refer to the above.    If the goal is to find words, none of the above solutions does that.
INPUT: "This. and:that.   with'the-other".
OUTPUT: ["This", "and", "that", "with", "the", "other"]
but what most of these "replaceAll" solutions is actually giving you is:
OUTPUT: ["This", "andthat", "withtheother"]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).