# Reverse words in a sentence

Tags: java, palindrome

I was able to check if the word that I entered was a palindrome or not. But how do I let it check for a whole sentence. Something like: A man, a plan, a cat, a ham, a yak, a yam, a hat, a canal-Panama!

Here is my Palindrome:

Output:

Enter a sentence: A man, a plan, a cat, a ham, a yak, a yam, a hat, a canal-Panama!

This sentence is not a palindrome.
//Shouldn't this be a palindrome too? So this is what I'm trying to get at. I want to enter a whole sentence.

However, if I do just one word:

Enter a sentence: abccba

This sentence is a palindrome.

Comment: What's the problem in your current code? And in your loop, why are you not `sentence.length()`?

Comment: Nothing really! I just want to know how can I enter a whole sentence like above and let it determine if it's palindrome or not. Let's me update the above a bit and you'll see what I mean

Comment: Why are you using Stack and Queue to solve the problem ?

Comment: I was required to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to check palindrome, is to reverse the whole string and compare it with the input string.

Since you got a way to check for palindrome already, just add few more filters to remove the space, remove all the punctuations then it will suit for a sentence as you need.

It's suggested to use Regex to achieve that, refer to [How can I remove punctuation from input text in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830813/how-can-i-remove-punctuation-from-input-text-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Your code starts by doing

```
String inputWord = sentence.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

This removs all the whitespace characters from the sentence. But it doesn't remove commas, hyphens, and other characters to ignore.

Comment: So is there anyway I can include them all?

Comment: include what in what? Your example sentence is only a palindrome if you don't take commas and hyphens into acount. Do you understand what a palindrome is? Do you understand the code you gave us, or did you blindly copied it from somewhere without understanding what it does?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove all signs that don't matter - whitespaces, quotation marks, any punctuation signs.
Also cast them toLower() or toUpper().
Though, I can see why this might be a fun experiment to do, it's not the most performant way to check for palindromes at all. You don't need to check every symbol, only half ofcourse :)

Comment: Yeah, just happen to have a reverse string class lying around, so a few more lines for queue and I basically got a palindrome. I was thinking of doing the one where I can just divide it in half, but realized I need to do queue stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the unwanted characters like

```
  str = str.replace(\W, "");
// W for [^[a-zA-Z_0-9]]
```

I haven't checked this for white spaces, and have assumed regex takes care of white space as well.

Answer (score 0):

Call your `isPalindrome` this way:

```
isPalindrome(sentence.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", "").toLowerCase())
```

and your problem is resolved. Try it this way:

```
String sentence = "A man, a plan, a cat, a ham, a yak, a yam, a hat, a canal-Panama!"
if (isPalindrome(sentence.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", "").toLowerCase()))
{
    System.out.println("It works");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("It does not work");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, still said not palindrome. I changed to similar to yours: `String inputWord = sentence.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z ]+", "");` and then I call `isPalindrome(inputString)`

Comment: Actually, can you debug your code and tell us what is the input string you got and where it came to the conclusion that the input was not a palindrome?