# How to write a method that removes punctuation?

Tags: punctuation

I am trying to write a method that receives a sentence (str) and prints it without punctuation (.,?!:").
Right now my method is removing some punctuation but not all.

```
public static String dePunct(String str)
{
    String noPunct = str;
    int length = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (str.charAt(i)=='.' || str.charAt(i)==','|| str.charAt(i)=='!'|| str.charAt(i)=='?'|| str.charAt(i)==':'|| str.charAt(i)=='"')
        {
            StringBuffer strSB = new StringBuffer(str);
            StringBuffer newStrSB =s trSB.replace(i,i+1, "");  
            noPunct = newStrSB.toString();
            length = noPunct.length();
        }
    }
    return noPunct;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830813/how-can-i-remove-punctuation-from-input-text-in-java

Comment: What programming language is this?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
String a = sentence.replaceAll("[.,:!\\?]","");
```