# How to remove all punctuation from a ArrayList<String>? Meaning "," and "."

Tags: selenium, arraylist, punctuation

I have an ArrayList that has numbers in it in a form of Strings, that are taken from a WebElement List (Copied into it).

I have 2 of these and I would like to compare between them, But because they have some "," and "." in these numbers I have difficulty to do that.

I have tried to look into similar questions such as 
[How can I remove punctuation from input text in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830813/how-can-i-remove-punctuation-from-input-text-in-java)

But have failed to implement it on my arrayList.

> The lists in the code can be easily located as :
>   / /         ***** LIST #1 - NEED TO IGNORE ALL NON_NUMERIC CHARACTERS *****///
>   and
>       ***** LIST #1 - NEED TO IGNORE ALL NON_NUMERIC CHARACTERS *****///

```
public static void WatchlistInstrumentsList(WebDriver driver, boolean finalstatus) throws InterruptedException
{

    List<Integer> memoryOfSelectedi = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // Remembering the 'Clock = Green' instruments


    int size = 2;
    int forCounter1=0;

    for (int i = 1; i < size ; i++) {
        forCounter1=i;

        // The selector of "Last" price = Streamer
        listOfLastPrice1= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[data-column-name='last'][class*='pid']")); 





// ***** LIST #1 - NEED TO IGNORE ALL NON_NUMERIC CHARACTERS *****///
    ArrayList<String> listCopyLastPrice1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (WebElement element : listOfLastPrice1) {
        listCopyLastPrice1.add(element.getText());
    }


    System.out.println("Number of Open stocks out of the list is: " +memoryOfSelectedi.size());



    WatchlistCheckSocket(driver, listCopyLastPrice1,  memoryOfSelectedi,listOfLastPrice1, forCounter1) ;
    finalstatus = true;
}






public static void WatchlistCheckSocket(WebDriver driver,List listCopyLastPrice1,
        List<Integer> memoryOfSelectedi,  List<WebElement> listOfLastPrice1, int forCounter1) throws InterruptedException
         {



    // ******** CHANGE LATTER TO 180000 ******///
    Thread.sleep(60000);


    List<WebElement> listOfLastPrice2=null;
    int size = 2;
    int forCounter2;


    for (int z = 0; z < size ; z++) {

        listOfLastPrice2= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[data-column-name='last'][class*='pid']")); 
        size = listOfLastPrice2.size();
        String NewPrice = listOfLastPrice2.get(z).getText();
        System.out.println("Last Price is: " +listOfLastPrice2.get(z).getText());

    }



// LIST #2 - NEED TO IGNORE ALL NON_NUMERIC CHARACTERS ///
    // Put all Values of WebElement listOfLastPrice2 List, into a String array list //
    ArrayList<String> listCopyLastPrice2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (WebElement element : listOfLastPrice2) {
        listCopyLastPrice2.add(element.getText());
    }




    // ****** COMPARE GREEN INSTRUMENTS, LIST1_Price VS LIST2_Price ****//
    int sizeList=0;
    while (sizeList<memoryOfSelectedi.size())
    {
        if (listCopyLastPrice1.get(memoryOfSelectedi.get(sizeList)) != listOfLastPrice2.get(memoryOfSelectedi.get(sizeList)).getText())
        {

            System.out.println("First price was: " +listCopyLastPrice1.get(memoryOfSelectedi.get(sizeList)));
            System.out.println("Second price was: " +listCopyLastPrice2.get(memoryOfSelectedi.get(sizeList)));


        }
        sizeList++;

    }}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'll modify my list's syntax to that, would this help?

```
 listCopyLastPrice2.add(element.getText().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", ""));
```

Comment: Well, it did help out in my output and punctuation.
BUT
for some reason when I getting to the (if) at the end, it sees all outputs from both lists as different (=!). even if I get the same values from both Lists. Why is that ?