# Boolean statement returning true of elements in string follow one another directly

Tags: java

I am fairly new to java and self taught as of now. I want to set up a Boolean statement such that for some given document of words eg

```
(“Hello”,”world”,”my”,”name”,”is”,”Luke”)
```

it would return true if the elements in a given string follow one another immediately eg `(“name”,”is”)` but false for `(“my”,”is”)`

I have tried to separate the document into an array of separate words but I’m struggling to understand the logic behind tracking if one directly follows the other and it outputs true or false.

So far:

```java
var words = new string[] (“Hello”,”world”,”my”,”name”...);

if (words[0].equals(“hello”) && words[1].equals(“world”)&&...)
```

I’m unsure how to proceed from here.

Comment: That new, that isnt correct java syntax?!

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC.  are you sure? How would I go about it the right way then?

Comment: First: are you sure you are programming in Java here? And. I would start by reading a good book or tutorial that reflects the version of java you intend to work with. For starters, String would need to be uppercase, and you would use { } instead of ( ) on that line ...

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC. I am using bluej as I’ve been told it’s the best way for beginners to learn?

Comment: This is particularly not a java question. It is a programming question where we apply different data structures and algorithms to solve such questions. Maybe do some problem-solving course in java. You can find such courses on hackerrank, hackerearth etc.

Comment: Maybe search what hashmaps are. They might help you.

Comment: I really dont understand your comment. BlueJ is the TOOL you use to write your code. What does that have to do with my advice "get a good book about java and follow that (instead of inventing your own syntax)"? I am not sure what your learning strategy is, but trust me: start by reading good books or tutorial. You need to create a bit of initial understanding before you write your own code. Look at existing code, then add your own ideas step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least as presented there were some issues getting your code to initialize the string array in Java. I adapted the variable declaration and indicated some of the other touches added in my Java code.
But to answer your question, to check if successive words are ever what you are looking for, you want to do what you would by hand. Look if word[0] and word[1] match what you seek. Then word[1] and word[2]. Finally word[n-2] and word[n-1]. If any of these are matches, the result is true. If none are matches, the result is false (the default value, flipped to true if there is a match). A loop will help iterate over the words (I chose the simple "for", but one could use an extended "for" or a "while").

```
public class WordPairFinder {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  //I am making everything lower case so that the matching is case insensitive, you may want to be explicit about wordOne.toLower() and wordTwo.toLower()   
  //when you make a method of this routine, wordOne and wordTwo will become parameters 
  String wordOne = "est"; //feel free to change this to test
  String wordTwo = "laborum"; //ditto
  String notSplit = "    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
  String[] words = notSplit.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase().split("\\s+");
  // above is from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830813/how-can-i-remove-punctuation-from-input-text-in-java
  boolean pairFound = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) { //note we have to stop at the penultimate word to avoid looking beyond the end of the array
   if (words[i].equals(wordOne) && words[i + 1].equals(wordTwo)) { //java wants normal quotes on its strings, check if current word followed by next word is the right pair
    pairFound = true;//you could break out of the loop here if you want
   }
  }
  System.out.println("With words " + wordOne + " and " + wordTwo + " value of pairFound is " + pairFound + ".");

 }
}
```

Comment: All I meant was that I think the person was using var in a way it would be used in a different language. But you are right, I was unaware you could even say "var" in java at all. Thanks for fixing that misimpression. If you think I should edit the answer, I will do so. If you think the comments suffice, I will leave it alone.

Comment: Note that `var` is available from Java 10 onwards.

Comment: Honestly, I dont like it personally when there are so many comments within source code, but I think: that is pure personal style ;-) ... way better now!

Comment: Hey I am trying to run this, I think I am having an error as it runs false every time, my data is in a hashmap which is a string but I think I need to somehow turn it into an integer

Comment: when you say your data is in a hash map, you mean your wordOne and wordTwo? Perhaps you can post that part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hash-map data-structure to solve this. Assign numeric keys to the words in your document and then you can check if a key corresponding to a word is consecutive to the key corresponding to the previous word.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give the code, because I'm not a java developer. The idea is that you loop through the array and check if a word matches at index i, and if the word at i+1 also matches.

```
for (i=0, i<array.count-1, i++){
   if (array[i] == firstWord && array[i+1] == secondword) {
        //here it is true
        break
    }
}
```

However I'd recommend you to use regex for these cases to be honest

Comment: in java == will not do what one thinks for strings. You want .equals. I agree with the logic.

Comment: yea, saw your comment later, it's way better than mine, so if you're reading this look at Jeremy's reply, or use regex